# Tableview not going bigger if expanding cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've implemented the thing where you click on cell or button and the `tableview` `cell` will expand. But the problem is if I expand the last `cell` it is behind the `tableview`. How can I make it to resize the `tableview` also and move the cell up a little?

I made it simply with constraints and `views` inside cell.

It looks like this, the **blue** one is main one and **black** is going to expand.

[image]

I don't know it the code is necessray but this is how I make it to expand.

This is inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if (self.selectedIndex == indexPath.row){
                self.selectedIndex = -1
            }else{
                self.selectedIndex  = indexPath.row
            }

            self.productstable.beginUpdates()
            self.productstable.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
            self.productstable.endUpdates()
        }
        return cell
```

This is inside `heightForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row){
    return 210
}else{
    return 135
}
```

I tried to detect the last `cell` and then move it up but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this code

```
func reloadChange()
{
     let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: selectedIndex, inSection: 0)
     self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
     //this is the way to scroll to your last cell
     self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     //code to expand and shrink your cell
     if(self.selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
      {
      self.selectedIndex = -1
      self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
     //this is the way to scroll to your last cell
     self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
        return
      }
    self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    self.reloadChange()
}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: It is working only for `cells` that are not the last one.

Comment: did you remove your code for your cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Ohh. It is actually working but it don't close anymore on second click. So it is doing what I wanted but broke something :D

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp my answer was edited I hope that finally all your requirements are done

Comment: Still the Signal Sigabrt on close because of invalid index path. I think I gotta figure it out on my own :)

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp my bad I will update my answer again, sorry for that

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp I had updated my answer, again, check now must work

Comment: Working perfectly, thank you. I actually don't understand what was changed :)